# Extracting Date from a Python list with elements of different lengths

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a python list `Timecount` where each element is a long strings with different indices but all with the same date. For example `Timecount[2]` looks like

```
23044   2021-07-07
23045   2021-07-07
23046   2021-07-07
23047   2021-07-07
23048   2021-07-07
           ...    
23165   2021-07-07
23166   2021-07-07
23167   2021-07-07
23168   2021-07-07
23169   2021-07-07
Name: Date, Length: 126, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

while `Timecount[8]` looks like

```
85316   2016-01-06
85317   2016-01-06
85318   2016-01-06
85319   2016-01-06
85320   2016-01-06
           ...    
85423   2016-01-06
85424   2016-01-06
85425   2016-01-06
85426   2016-01-06
85427   2016-01-06
Name: Date, Length: 112, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I want to create a new list where each element consists of the date only, so for example `newlist[2]` is just `2021-07-07`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have python list where values are `pd.Series`. To get only the first value from each series you can use `.iat[]`:

```py
lst = [
    pd.Series(["2021-07-07", "2021-07-07"], name="Date"),
    pd.Series(["2021-01-06", "2021-01-06"], name="Date"),
]

out = [series.iat[0] for series in lst]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['2021-07-07', '2021-01-06']
```